# Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting this TypeScript error even though I have wrapped it in undefined checks. I just can't seem to be able to get rid of it. `message.payload` on the second line of code has the red lines underneath it.

`(property) Message.payload?: Payload | undefined Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)`

```js
if (message && message.payload && message.payload.data) {
  setDependentPayloads((prev) => `${prev} ${(message.payload.data)}`);
}
```

## Update

Here is the error in the editor:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

an exclamation point tells TS you have checked and are certain this element exists.

Try `message.payload!` and `message.payload!.data!`

Comment: Thank you @jsw324 - I am trying to access `message.payload.data` - I have updated the question above. Where should I put the exclamation? After `data` it doesn't work.

Comment: try `message.payload!.data!`